# how to use razor template between " "

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am trying to write razor template in link

```
 <a asp-action="Details/@(customerModel.CustomerId)" class="button">Detail</a>
```

but in html it renders like this

> https://localhost:44316/User/Details%2F92e48182-6bc8-4c88-8de9-a7e0b5715f2b

the id is 92e48182-6bc8-4c88-8de9-a7e0b5715f2b

why it doesn't render like this?

> https://localhost:44316/User/Details/92e48182-6bc8-4c88-8de9-a7e0b5715f2b

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<a  asp-action="Details" asp-controller="User" asp-route-id="@Model.CustomerId" 
class="button"> Details </a>
```